# Animating images in Plymouth

Tags: 14.04, plymouth, animations

I'm trying to animate an image for a custom plymouth boot theme. I can get the object to move by pixel increments, but it does not update fast enough to be smooth. I don't quite understand the trick to refresh the screen at certain frame intervals. The code I have looks like this:

```
wallpaper_image = Image("Win95.png");
plane_image = Image("paperairplaneShadow.png");
screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
resized_wallpaper_image = wallpaper_image.Scale(screen_width,screen_height);
plane_sprite = Sprite(plane_image);

wallpaper_sprite = Sprite(resized_wallpaper_image);
wallpaper_sprite.SetZ(-100);

progress=0;
fun refresh_callback ()
 {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    plane_images[i] = Image("paperairplaneShadow" + i + ".png");
    plane_sprite = Sprite();
}


plane_sprite.SetImage(plane_images[Math.Int(progress/6) % 4]);
//plane_sprite.SetImage(plane_images[]);
plane_sprite.SetX(progress);
//plane_sprite.SetY(progress);


 progress++;


 }
Plymouth.SetUpdateStatusFunction(refresh_callback);
```

I was following the tutorial at http://brej.org/blog/?p=197. I can't figure out how the frame rate change works:

```
butterfly_sprite.SetImage(butterfly_images[Math.Int(progress / 6) % 4]);
```

The site says it should put up the next image in the butterfly.sprite array (which has 4 images) every 6 frames. In my script, the plane_sprite will update, but only about once a second. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/posts/147769